How to use an image from AWS S3 in email in a Laravel Project
I have laravel project that sends email using Laravel's builtin mailer (Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail). I can send text emails without any issue. My site is hosted on AWS and I store images in AWS S3 which is not public.
To include an image from S3, I believe that it needs to be embedded. Any suggestion how to do this? I am passing details to the blade file in the build() method like this:
public function build()
    {
        $this->subject('You have missed an interaction scheduled for ' . $this->schedule->clientname);
        return $this->view('emails.scheduleMissedCheckinToWorker')
            ->replyTo( $this->schedule->schedulerEmail,  $this->schedule->schedulername )
            ->with([
              'schedule' => $this->schedule,
             ]);
        ;
    }

I have full path to the image at AWS. Perhaps I need to Get it and somehow pass it to the blade file. Any help is appreciated.
UPDATE:
chatgpt suggested the following apprach
public function build()
{
    // Retrieve the image from S3
    $imageData = Storage::disk('s3')->get($this->missedSchedule->worker_image_path);

    return $this->view('emails.scheduleMissedCheckin')
        ->subject('An interaction you scheduled for ' . $this->missedSchedule->clientname . ' was not checked into by ' . $this->missedSchedule->workername)
        ->replyTo($this->missedSchedule->workerEmail, $this->missedSchedule->workername)
        ->with(['missedSchedule' => $this->missedSchedule])
        ->attachData($imageData, 'worker.jpg', [
            'mime' => 'image/jpeg',
            'as' => 'worker.jpg',
            'content_id' => 'workerImage'
        ])
        ->withSwiftMessage(function ($message) {
            $message->embedFromPath('worker.jpg', 'workerImage');
        });
}

And use the following in the blade file:
<img src="cid:workerImage" alt="Worker Image" width="200" height="200">

But it did not work for me. Any one having any experience with this approach.

You can: 1) obtain a presigned request for the img 2) use a public access bucket

Read What is this site’s policy on content generated by generative artificial intelligence tools?

@pierpy: I can't make the bucket public. I don't get 'presigned request for the img'. All I need is that the image appears in the email, whether the email is opened today or 10 days later.
The AI generated content I have included in my question is just for reference; it is not an answer to my question. It has been included so that any reader who has used similar code may give their answer.

Ok, this is unclear. No public bucket, no presign. So, what's stopping you from including the img? You say: "I believe that it needs to be embedded." How, without a presign / public bucket? If the 7 days limit is a problem, ok

@pierpy I am sorry for the confusion. In you first comment, you said, "1) obtain a presigned request for the img". What I wanted to say is that I don't know "obtain a presigned request for the img". Could you please explain what is this? My bucket is private and I can't make it public. All I need is to include an image from that bucket in the email, so that it is visible to email recipients any time they open it, whether today, tomorrow, in 7 days or next month.

Ok, no problem. But if you have a physical file on your server,  are you able to include it in the email? I can help for the other part, S3

All my image files are on AWS S3. I will try to upload one on the server. Since this server is a production server, I will do it when not many people are using it and I have time to test and/or rollback if something goes wrong. I will get back to you. Thanks for your help.

What you are looking for is probably found here: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/mail#inline-attachments , if you have access to the file on S3, you can embed it and send it this way. S3 or not seems irrelevant in this case.

#1 Usually email images are public. If your images are the company logo or some cool effect, I suggest you to host them in a public s3. Explain to your boss that even biggest companies do that. An exception could be if you are working for CIA, KGB, etc #2 Is the image a kind of report? If this is the case, attach the image as file.

I believe that embedding images as suggested by Dimitri Mostrey will work for me. Attachment is not an option as I need to include small images of workers and clients in the email along with their names. Thanks everyone for your help.
